# sudo: unable to change directory to /root: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, sudo

I have a problem, because I installed nvm and then I tried to uninstall but I made some mess...
When I run "sudo -i" I get this:

> sudo: unable to change directory to /root: No such file or directory
>
> sudo: unable to execute /bin/bash: No such file or directory

Someone could help me? Thank you!!

Comment: _Do not power off the computer._ What have you done, exactly? Do you have backups?

Comment: eh I was stupid because I gave a few commands that I found on the web something like: rm -rf $NVM_DIR ~/.npm ~/.bower

Comment: If I run the command sudo -s I find root

Comment: Were you root/sudo when you issued the `rm` commands?

Comment: BACKUP your data!! DO NOT log out or shut it down.

Comment: yes I was in root

Comment: I have already logged out too...

Comment: You have damaged Linux, so save your data. You may need to reinstall.